# Patio roof rafter spacing

Tags: roof, patio

I want to replace the roofing on an older shed style covered patio.  The patio was built 45 years ago (+/-).  The rafters are 2x8 with an odd spacing I've never seen before, alternating 21 inches OC,then 17 inches OC then 21 then 17, with blocking about 4'.  Was this a thing back then or is it a one off homeowner project?  The framing is still solid and I don't want to tear it down, just re-roof.  The roofing material is corrugated fiberglass panels only, they are original. If this was a thing, is there a roofing plan for how to start laying panels?  What width panels would I use?

Comment: Well if you average it out they're 19" on center.. ;)

Comment: Could the odd spacing be necessary because of the corrugated roofing?  Seems odd to me but could that be it?

Answer (score 1):

We use 19.2" oc joists (5 spaces for 8' plywood) when we use Trus-Joist open web joists. They are so expensive that keeping size down and spacing maximized saves costs. (True-Joist has a software program to figure this out...)

Maybe the alternating spacing allow fasteners to secure the corrugated roofing on the "down" curve of the corrugated shape.

I think this old-time carpenter was ahead of his time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason I can see for the alternating spacing, except for the builders choice or homeowners. So I believe you have a one off framing job.

Since the average of increment is 19", it is probably more accurately 19 3/16".
This is a not so commonly used framing center to work with 8' material. I can't say if that is what they were striving for that, but it seems to look that way.